# video recording in yii framework

Tags: video, yii, video-capture, video-processing, yii-extensions

I am new to yii framework and I want to develop an app where I can record video and send to other person. Is there any way I can implement it using the framework or any other method. I searched but found nothing.

can you please guide me in the right direction

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual recording of the video has little to do with PHP, let alone the framework you use. 
You'll have to look at video technologies like Wowza, Red5 or Adobe Media Server. You can code the management of those videos in PHP using Yii of course, but PHP as a language will not help you in your main issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [CameraTag.com](http://www.CameraTag.com).  We're in the middle of adding it to our system and are fairly pleased with how it works so far.